# set jenkins environment variable in pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to set a Jenkins environment variable where I can get html values and pass it downstream for filtering in parameters stage. I am unable to do so, here we have minimal example

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    environment {
        get = new URL("http://company_server:port/packages/").openConnection(); 
        getRC = get.getInputStream().getText() // set getRC  and access this value for result (highlited with ***********) 
        }
        stages {
            stage('Parameters'){
                steps {
                    script {
                    properties([
                            parameters([
                                [$class: 'ChoiceParameter', 
                                    choiceType: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT', 
                                    description: '',
                                    name: 'foo',
                                    filterLength: 1, 
                                    filterable: true,  
                                    script: 
                                        [$class: 'GroovyScript', 
                                        fallbackScript: [
                                                classpath: [], 
                                                sandbox: false, 
                                                script: "return['']"
                                                ], 
                                        script: [
                                                classpath: [], 
                                                sandbox: false, 
                                                script: '''
                                                    def result = (getRC =~ /(">)pip_pkgs[^<]*/).findAll()
                                                    def sublist = []
                                                    result.each {
                                                      sublist.add(it[0].split(",")[0].replace('">', ''))
                                                    }
                                                    return sublist
                                                '''
                                            ] 
                                    ]
                                ],
                            ])
                        ])
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The `environment` block is for setting shell environment variables. You appear to want to set global Groovy Pipeline variables instead. If you migrate the variables, then it should start functioning correctly.

Answer (score 1):

check here : [jenkins environment variables](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/environment/)

```
stages {
    stage('Build') {
        steps {
            echo "Database engine is ${DB_ENGINE}"
            echo "DISABLE_AUTH is ${DISABLE_AUTH}"
            sh 'printenv'
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using a variable that was set as an environment variable, you have to use like this: `${your_variable}` (See [Using environment variables](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/environment/))

In your case:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    environment {
        get = new URL("http://company_server:port/packages/").openConnection(); 
        getRC = get.getInputStream().getText() // set getRC and access this value for result (highlited with ***********) 
        }
        stages {
            stage('Parameters'){
                steps {
                    script {
                    properties([
                            parameters([
                                [$class: 'ChoiceParameter', 
                                    choiceType: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT', 
                                    description: '',
                                    name: 'foo',
                                    filterLength: 1, 
                                    filterable: true,  
                                    script: 
                                        [$class: 'GroovyScript', 
                                        fallbackScript: [
                                                classpath: [], 
                                                sandbox: false, 
                                                script: "return['']"
                                                ], 
                                        script: [
                                                classpath: [], 
                                                sandbox: false, 
                                                script: '''
                                                    def result = (${getRC} =~ /(">)pip_pkgs[^<]*/).findAll()
                                                    def sublist = []
                                                    result.each {
                                                      sublist.add(it[0].split(",")[0].replace('">', ''))
                                                    }
                                                    return sublist
                                                '''
                                            ] 
                                    ]
                                ],
                            ])
                        ])
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```